# Exception while trying to deploy jpdl in wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly, jbpm

We are getting the following error while trying to deploy JPDL in wildfly.

```
2015-10-13 14:41:23,280 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-3) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'deploymentManager' defined in class path resource [com/servicelive/orderfulfillment/contexts/jBPMContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.servicelive.orderfulfillment.jbpm.WFProcessDeploymentManager]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1045) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) [spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) [spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:193) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.servicelive.orderfulfillment.jbpm.WFProcessDeploymentManager]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:121) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentMap.keySet(PersistentMap.java:250) [hibernate-3.3.2.GA.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.repository.DeploymentImpl.getResourceNames(DeploymentImpl.java:155) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:197) [hibernate-3.3.2.GA.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.repository.DeploymentImpl_$$_javassist_27.getResourceNames(DeploymentImpl_$$_javassist_27.java) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.jpdl.internal.repository.JpdlDeployer.deploy(JpdlDeployer.java:52) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.repository.DeployerManager.deploy(DeployerManager.java:46) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.repository.RepositorySessionImpl.getObject(RepositorySessionImpl.java:119) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.query.ProcessDefinitionQueryImpl.execute(ProcessDefinitionQueryImpl.java:72) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.query.AbstractQuery.untypedList(AbstractQuery.java:64) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.query.ProcessDefinitionQueryImpl.list(ProcessDefinitionQueryImpl.java:141) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.jpdl.internal.repository.JpdlDeployer.checkKey(JpdlDeployer.java:112) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.jpdl.internal.repository.JpdlDeployer.deploy(JpdlDeployer.java:83) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.repository.DeployerManager.deploy(DeployerManager.java:46) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.repository.RepositorySessionImpl.deploy(RepositorySessionImpl.java:55) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.cmd.DeployCmd.execute(DeployCmd.java:46) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.cmd.DeployCmd.execute(DeployCmd.java:32) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.DefaultCommandService.execute(DefaultCommandService.java:42) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.spring.CommandTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(CommandTransactionCallback.java:50) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131) [spring-tx-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.tx.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:79) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.EnvironmentInterceptor.execute(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:54) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.RetryInterceptor.execute(RetryInterceptor.java:55) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.repository.DeploymentImpl.deploy(DeploymentImpl.java:89) [jbpm-4.0.0.xby2patched.jar:]
```

Comment: Not exactly unexpected when you deploy such legacy technology on an application server which is not legacy. JBPM 4 was never tested against it. Any kind of help with this matter will require far more than only the resulting exception, you'll need to detail what you did to set this up.

Comment: Hi I am getting the following error while trying to deploy jpdl4 in wildfly using jdk1.8. It seems like this it related to rt.jar.We have seen this exception while trying to migrate from jboss 4 to wildfly.

Comment: Please find below the exception while parsing the jpdl.

Comment: xml validation error: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document. [line=1715 column=1 ]: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1715; columnNumber: 1; An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document.
  error: couldn't parse xml document [line=1715 column=1 ]: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1715; columnNumber: 1; An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the

Comment: Posting more errors does not help you or anyone else, you need to detail what setup steps you did so far. As this article will show, it is not as easy as installing a server and plopping the application into it. And this is for JBPM 5 even: http://kverlaen.blogspot.com/2011/07/jbpm5-on-as7-lightning.html